# Group re-occurring rows and find time difference from single datetime column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with a time column, and then a value column which has repeating A/B values. I need to be able to group these values into pairs and find the timedelta between them.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time1'] = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=6, freq='H') 
df['id'] = range(1,7)
df['val'] = ['A','B'] * 3

                 time  id val
0 2018-01-01 00:00:00   1   A
1 2018-01-01 01:00:00   2   B
2 2018-01-01 02:00:00   3   A
3 2018-01-01 03:00:00   4   B
4 2018-01-01 04:00:00   5   A
5 2018-01-01 05:00:00   6   B
```

needs to be...

```
index        diff     A   B
  0      01:00:00     1   2
  1      01:00:00     3   4
  2      01:00:00     5   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a pair_id, this will be used to identify pairs. Add this to the df

```
pair_id = sorted(list(range(0, int(df.shape[0]/2))) * 2)
df.loc[:, 'pair'] = pair_id
```

Define a difference function

```
def diff(x):
    return max(x) - min(x)
```

Using `groupby` make the difference calculation

```
diff_df = df.groupby('pair')['time1'].apply(diff).to_frame('diff')
```

And group the remaining data

```
id_df = df.groupby(['pair','val'])['id'].sum().unstack()
```

So we have `diff_df`:

```
         diff
pair         
0    01:00:00
1    01:00:00
2    01:00:00
```

And `id_df`:

```
val   A  B
pair      
0     1  2
1     3  4
2     5  6
```

Join these two

```
diff_df.join(id_df)
         diff  A  B
pair               
0    01:00:00  1  2
1    01:00:00  3  4
2    01:00:00  5  6
```

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a much simpler/faster way to do this within Pandas, but given your example data, here is something I came up with that seems to work. It uses the [`grouper()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe from the `itertools` docs to pull the rows 2 at a time from the dataframe, and then takes the timedelta and merges into one new row.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

new_rows = []
for a, b in grouper(df.iterrows(), 2):
    tdelta = b[1][0] - a[1][0]
    aid = a[1][1]
    bid = b[1][1]
    new_rows.append({'diff': tdelta, 'A': aid, 'B': bid})
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows)
new_df = new_df.reindex(columns=['diff', 'A', 'B'])
```

Which gives:

```
>>> print(new_df)
      diff  A  B
0 01:00:00  1  2
1 01:00:00  3  4
2 01:00:00  5  6
```

... But Dillon's solution above is much cleaner, and probably much more efficient :)